# How do I make jQuery wait for a recursive function to finish?

Tags: jquery, jquery-callback

I'm trying to animate a series of elements, one by one, and then, when all of them have finished animating execute some code.

Here's what I have so far:

```
// this function is called on mouseleave or a click
function hideItems(){
    var opts = {duration:100, direction:"down", easing:"easeOutExpo"};
    $("li").last().hide("drop", opts, function hidePrev(){
        $(this).prev("li").hide("drop", opts, hidePrev);
    });
    $("ul").css('display','none');// i need this to wait
}
```

I'm going over all the `li` elements, and hiding them. I need the `ul` element hidden *after* the `li` elements have been iterated over.

I've tried something along these lines without success:

```
// this function is called on mouseleave or a click
function hideItems(){
    var opts = {duration:100, direction:"down", easing:"easeOutExpo"};
    $("li").last().hide("drop", opts, function hidePrev(){
        $(this).prev("li").hide("drop", opts, hidePrev);
    }).then(function(){
        $("ul").css('display','none');
    });// this fails with: 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'
}
```

Comment: Callbacks. Callbacks.

Comment: in your hidePrev function, you need a conditional that tests if they've all been hidden. If they've all been hidden, hide the ul. If you instead wanted to use a promise, you would ahve to attach it to all li's of the ul, however i'm pretty sure it would fire only the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a recursive function that is selecting the last *visible* `li` via the `:visible` pseudoclass:

```
var opts = {duration:100, direction:'down', easing:'easeOutExpo'};

function recursiveHide(){
    $('li:visible').last().hide('drop', opts).promise().then(function(){
        if ($('li:visible').length){
            recursiveHide();
        } else {
            $('ul').hide();
        }
    });
}
recursiveHide();
```

Also note that you need to call `.promise()` on an animated jQuery-Object to gain access to its `thenable` interface.

See a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Kp8N/)**.